# Fetch data based on ID that has same ID's in other table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table `tasks` and `users` that have `tasks_ids` from the `tasks` table. I would like to show only the tasks data that users have based on his `tasks_ids`. Please see illustration below.

`tasks` table

```
---------------
-- id | name --
-- 1  | task1 --
-- 2  | task2 --
-- 3  | task3 --
---------------
```

`users` table

```
----------------------------
-- id | name  | tasks_ids --
-- 1  | Ryan  | 1         --
-- 2  | Joe   | 1, 2      --
-- 3  | Mark  | 1, 2, 3   --
----------------------------
```

Below is my code but it only shows if user has only 1 task.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Task Name</td>
  </tr>
  @foreach($tasks as $task)
    @if($task->id == Auth::user()->tasks_id)
      <tr>
        <td>{{$task->name}}</td>
      </tr>
    @endif
  @endforeach
</table>
```

If I logged in as Joe the excepted output should be:

```
---------------
-- Task Name --
-- task1     --
-- task2     --
---------------
```

Comment: Show us your fetch query.

Comment: Actually, `user` table should be redesigned. `tasks_ids` should not exist. Have a tasktouser table. Then join the three tables together and you can pull all the tasks you require. Current implementation would be very inefficient as all tasks would need to be pulled for every load. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad if unfamiliar.

Comment: Performing queiries on `CSV` fields can be troublesome and generally recommended to avoid. Consider using something like a [`pivot table`](https://laraveldaily.com/post/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships) instead.

Comment: Possibly `explode(',', Auth::user()->tasks_id)` and `in_array` but really should reconsider the whole process.

Comment: Agreed with all the comments above. `users.tasks_ids` column should be deleted, and the values in each should be moved to a `pivot_table`, like `task_user` (if going by Laravel's conventions), then you'd be able to define a [`belongsToMany()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship between `User` and `Task`. You'd then be able to do `@foreach(auth()->user()->tasks as $task)`, or `Task Count: {{ auth()->user()->tasks->count() }}`, etc. This _can_ be done with your code, but not easily, and definitely not efficiently.

Comment: Thank you for all comments and suggestions.